# Como puedo subir carpeta, subcarpetas y todo lo que estas carpetas contengan a miservidor FTP con C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ftp

Como puedo subir mis carpetas a mi servidor FTP y asi hay subcarpetas que tambien se suban junto con todos los archivos que tengan dentro.
Tengo el siguiente codigo y esto solo me sube el nombre de la carpeta y los archivos que hay dentro. Si hay una carpeta dentro o mas no se suben.

```
 protected static void UploadFile(string FilePath, string RemotePath, string Login, string Password, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string url = RemotePath + "/Backup-PC-Directoy/" + fileName;
                FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login, Password);
                ftp.KeepAlive = false;
                ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                ftp.UseBinary = true;
                ftp.ContentLength = fs.Length;
                ftp.Proxy = null;
                byte[] buff = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                fs.Close();
                Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
                ftpstream.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                ftpstream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Con un método recursivo puedes hacerlo, obteniendo todos los nombres de los archivos y todos los sub-directorios del directorio actual para guardarlos en `Array`, luego iterar para cada sub-directorio y realizar el mismo procedimiento.

```
protected static void UploadFile(string FilePath, string RemotePath, string Login, string Password)
{
    try
    {
        string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath, "*.*");
        string[] Paths = Directory.GetDirectories(FilePath);
        foreach (string file in Files)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RemotePath + Path.GetFileName(file));
                ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login, Password);
                ftp.KeepAlive = false;
                ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                ftp.UseBinary = true;
                ftp.ContentLength = fs.Length;
                ftp.Proxy = null;
                byte[] buff = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                fs.Close();
                Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
                ftpstream.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                ftpstream.Close();
            }
        }
        foreach (string path in Paths)
        {
            UploadFile(path, RemotePath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(path), Login, Password);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: aunque tiene mucho sentido tu propuesta, cuando se topa con archivos .ini deja de funcionar y se va al catch, lo seguire revisando quizas pueda cambiar esa parte, ya que solo deben de contener archivos, word, excel e imagenes.

Comment: Puedes agregar que excepción te muestra, o simplemente agregas el filtro `if (!Path.GetFileName(file).Contains(".ini")) { }`

Answer (score 0):

Opción 1:

- Puedes enviar todo tu contenido *(carpetas, sub-carpetas y demás)* en un archivo .zip, y descomprimirlo en el servidor.

Opción 2:

- Crear un método recursivo al que le pases la URL de la carpeta a la cual conectarse y allí descargar los elementos que contiene la carpeta.

Comment: podria servir el .zip, sin embargo donde se pasaria mi carpeta a .zip. Es buena la idea, siendo sincero no ayuda mucho sin un pequeño ejemplo de lo que dices.

Comment: @Manny tienes toda la razón y gracias por la sinceridad en tu comentario. Estaba pensando que puedes colocar el .zip en la carpeta raíz `"/"` *(o en la carpeta)* que tengas pensado llevar todos tus archivos*. No poseo un código que puedas usar para este caso específico, pero, puedes intentar con [Ionic.Zip.dll](http://csharpalextremo.blogspot.com/2012/07/comprimir-y-descomprimir-archivos-en.html) para comprimir y descomprimir un .zip usando C#.